# Show the parse data in a table

Tags: php, dom

I want to parse data from the following link.
 **http://www.dsebd.org/news_archive_7days.php**
Here is my code for the task.I want to show the data in a tabular form. Please help me to find where i am going wrong

```
<?php

    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');


    $url = "http://www.dsebd.org/news_archive_7days.php/";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr');
    foreach($tables as $div) {

    if ($div->getElementsByTagName('td') ) {
        echo $div ->nodeValue;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this code (note that I included a line that removes the horizontal lines to make it easier to process):

```
// added this line
$html = str_replace('<tr>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#DDDDDD"><span class="style1"><hr></span></td>
  </tr>', '', $html);

$dom = new DOMDocument();

@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');

$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

$result = array();

$i = 0;
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $i++;
    if($i < 4){
        continue;
    }
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    $item = $cols->item(1);

    if($item){
        if($i % 4 === 0){
            $tmp = array();
            $tmp['trading_code'] = $item->nodeValue;
        }elseif($i % 4 === 1){
            $tmp['title'] = $item->nodeValue;
        }elseif($i % 4 === 2){
            $tmp['news'] = $item->nodeValue;
        }elseif($i % 4 === 3){
            $tmp['post_date'] = $item->nodeValue;
            $result[] = $tmp;
        }
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output is something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [trading_code] => SHY
            [title] => DSENEWS: Withdrawal of Authorized Representative
            [news] => Withdrawal of Authorized Representative: Shyamol Equity Management Limited, DSE TREC No. 3, has withdrawn one of its Authorized Representatives, Mr. Mohammad Hannan, with immediate effect.
            [post_date] => 2016-03-10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [trading_code] => EXCH
            [title] => DSENEWS: Daily Turnover
            [news] => Today's (10.03.2016) Total Trades: 95,239; Volume: 111,966,997 and Turnover: Tk. 3,834.00 million.
            [post_date] => 2016-03-10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [trading_code] => EXCH
            [title] => DSE News: Monthly Review
            [news] => The Monthly Review ÃÂ February 2016 has been published. Investors and any other interested person may collect copies of the same from DSE Reception or DSE Sales Center at 9/F and 9/E (7th Floor), Motijheel C/A, Dhaka-1000 respectively. Mob: 01713-425810, Ph: 9564601, 9576210-18 Ext-106, 188, 249. This book is also available at DSE Chittagong Office at Shafi Bhaban (2nd Floor), Agrabad C/A, Chittagong, Sylhet Office at RN Tower (5th & 6th Floor), Chowhatta, Sylhet-3100.
            [post_date] => 2016-03-10
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [trading_code] => DUTCHBANGL
            [title] => DUTCHBANGL: Spot for AGM
            [news] => Trading of the shares of the Company will be allowed only in the Spot Market and Block transactions will also be settled as per spot settlement cycle with cum benefit from 13.03.2016 to 14.03.2016. Trading of the shares of the Company will remain suspended on record date i.e., 15.03.2016.
            [post_date] => 2016-03-10
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [trading_code] => UCB
            [title] => UCB: Spot for AGM
            [news] => Trading of the shares of the Company will be allowed only in the Spot Market and Block transactions will also be settled as per spot settlement cycle with cum benefit from 13.03.2016 to 14.03.2016. Trading of the shares of the Company will remain suspended on record date i.e., 15.03.2016.
            [post_date] => 2016-03-10
        )
// ... and goes on ...
```

---

That way you can access specific values:

```
echo 'Trading code  : ' . $result[1]['trading_code'] . '<br>';
echo 'Title         : ' . $result[1]['title'] . '<br>';
echo 'News          : ' . $result[1]['news'] . '<br>';
echo 'Post Date     : ' . $result[1]['post_date'] . '<br>';
```

Output:

> Trading code : EXCH 
>   Title : DSENEWS: Daily Turnover 
>   News : Today's (10.03.2016) Total Trades: 95,239; Volume: 111,966,997 and Turnover: Tk. 3,834.00 million. 
>   Post Date : 2016-03-10

You could use a loop, create a table, etc. Use your imagination...

---

**Warning:**

I have no information about the website's terms on scraping and bots, so **use at your own risk!!** (You should definitely look into that issue and find out about their position)

Comment: It was a great Help. Thanks A lot

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

can be [download from](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/)

```
include_once "simple_html_dom.php";
$html = file_get_html('http://www.dsebd.org/news_archive_7days.php/');
foreach($html->find('tr') as $element)
echo $element; '<br>';
```